# build failed with error 'file not found' and 'linker command failed with exit code 1 '

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I really searched stackoverflow for hours and on the internet, but couldn't find the answer why its happening. So before I create a new project I decided to post a question here.

Using Xcode 6.

[image: error]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to re-create the "scheme".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution. So apparently when you try to change your bundle id, it's better not to change the whole project name, just the bundle id in the .plist file.

What I did is to change to whole project name and than the error occurred, maybe some kind of bug, when I changed it back to what it was before, the issue has been fixed and the build succeeded.

If you want to change the bundle id, do it from the .plist file.

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete derived data from  the organiser for the app.

or

try reset simulator than clean and run the app

Comment: delete  all data from  simulator derived data path  that is being shown in this error. just use go to folder and paste that path than  delete all data there